# React, wrong parent state

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent, with some child's. On parent I have an state:

```
this.state = {
  valuesInInput: {}
}
```

I render some child's:

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <NomForm data={this.state.data} crtID={this.state.selectedID}
    <NomData tableName={this.state.tableName} data={this.state.data} setCrtID={this.setCurrentID} />
      handleValueInInput={this.handleValueInInput} addData={this.addData} />
  </div>
);
}
```

Next, I have some functions where I process some liftups:
First one:

```
setCurrentID = async (id) => {
 //depending on id, I set an object, cpy
 let cpy = {};
 //... populating cpy with some values
 await this.setState(() => { return { selectedID: id, valueInInput: cpy } } 
}
```

Here, when I console.log *valueInInput*, it works perfectly fine.
The second one:

```
 handleValueInInput = async (field, value) => {
  let cpy = Object.assign({}, this.state.valuesInInput);
  cpy[field] = value;
  await this.setState(() => { return { valueInInput: cpy } });
 }
```

Here I get *valueOfInput* as an empty object, despite the fact that I have throwed some data in it with the first call, *setCurrentID*. In rest, works fine, I have the key and the value there, but only one element.
On the child size:
-*setCurrentID* is a handler for a onClick button event in one child component ;
-*handleValueInInput* is a handler for an *onChange* input text box in a second child component.

Everything works fine separately. The principle is that first I set *valueInInput* with *setCurrentID* then I use it on *handleValueInInput*. It does not work, I've try with some *forceUpdate()*, no joy. Every time, in *handleValueInInput* the state *valueInInput* in empty.

Any help, please... Thank you!

Comment: Why are you awaiting setState?

Comment: @JMadelaine: I  have only one week in React. Somewhere in internet I've seen this approach. And because I've read that setState is asynchronous.  Anyway, this is the last desperate wrong version. I've try without async/await, also. State which I've set in first function is not available in second one. I miss something, but I don't know what.

Comment: Await is used to await promises. You said this is your first week learning React. Is it also your first week learning JavaScript? You should learn the basics of JavaScript before learning React.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I found it!
Usually *valuesInInput* its not the same as *valueInInput*. I've found this error after two days, using React Developer Tools. Using it I've found that I have a wrong state there. Very useful thing. A beginner mistake, I was not sure about state behaviour.
And I gave rid of this async/await thing, now it works like a charm.